# Loop over every name and check to see if name begins with 'A'

Tags: javascript, arrays

Loop over every name and check to see if name begins with 'A'
If it does add a message to output array saying No gift for {person's name}
Otherwise, add a message to output array saying {Person's name} loved their gift!

```js
var person;
var gift;
function christmasTree(people){
   var output = [];
for (var i =0; i<person.length; i++){
    if (person.startsWith ("Aimee")){
      output.push(No gift for Aimee.);
    }
    if (person.startsWith ("Ariana"){
       output.push(No gift for Ariana.);
    }
    else {
    output.push(person[i] loved their gift);
    }
    return output;
}
person = ['Aimee', 'Ariana', 'Billy', 'Joel', 'Zaire', 'Lily']
gift = christmasTree [person, 'gift'];
console.log(gift);
//Output should look like: 
// This should be output:
  //   [
  //     "Billy loved their gift!",
  //     "Joel loved their gift!",
 //     "No gift for Aimee",
 //     "No gift for Ariana",
 //     "Zaire loved their gift!",
 //     "Lily loved their gift!",
 //  ]
```

*Having trouble getting the required output. Please advise on what how I can fix this.

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what exactly you're having problems with.

Comment: `if ( person.indexOf('a') === 0 ) ...`

Comment: What's the use of people here in christmasTree function. And is that correct ? gift = christmasTree [person, 'gift'];

Comment: *Having trouble* is not a problem description. What specific trouble are you having? And *please advise on a fix* is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

there are  a few issues with your code, you should check for `people.length` inside `christmasTree(people)`. And thats not how you call a function, to call use `christmasTree(person)`. Then if you are iterating over people you need to actually check for each element inside the array use `people[i]` for that.

```js
var person;
var gift;
function christmasTree(people){
   var output = [];
for (var i=0; i<people.length; i++){
    if (people[i].toUpperCase().startsWith("A")){
      output.push("No gift for " + person[i]);
    }
    else {
      output.push(people[i] + " loved their gift");
    }
  }
    return output;
}
person = ['Aimee', 'Ariana', 'Billy', 'Joel', 'Zaire', 'Lily'];
gift = christmasTree(person);
console.log(gift);
//Output should look like: 
// This should be output:
  //   [
  //     "Billy loved their gift!",
  //     "Joel loved their gift!",
 //     "No gift for Aimee",
 //     "No gift for Ariana",
 //     "Zaire loved their gift!",
 //     "Lily loved their gift!",
 //  ]
```

Comment: if (people[i].startsWith("A")||people[i].startsWith("a"))
for case sensitive 
or if(people[i].tolowercase().startsWith("a"))

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some errors in the code that you have posted, for instance, the array object should be accessed as follows:
person[i].startsWith("A") instead of *person.startsWith("A")*

please take a look at the following snippet:

```js
function christmasTree(people){
    var output = [];
    for (var i =0; i<person.length; i++){
        if (person[i].toLowerCase().startsWith("a")) {
            output.push('No gift for' + person[i]);
        }
        else {
            output.push(person[i] + ' loved their gift');
        }
    }
return output;
}
person = ['Aimee', 'Ariana', 'Billy', 'Joel', 'Zaire', 'Lily'];
gift = christmasTree(person);
console.log(gift);
```